# Can't receive output from DSPLIBL (as400.access package)

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to connect to an AS/400 server using java, and would like to run some simple commands.

My imports are:

```
    import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400;
    import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400Message;
    import com.ibm.as400.access.CommandCall;
```

This is what I have thus far:

```
    AS400 as400 = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        as400 = new AS400(host);            
        as400.setUserId(user);
        as400.setPassword(pass);
        CommandCall cmd = new CommandCall(as400);


        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Ready for input, type \"quit\" to end session");
            String commandStr = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Command entered: " + commandStr);
            if(commandStr.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Executing: " + commandStr);

            boolean success = cmd.run(commandStr.toUpperCase());
            System.out.println("Finished execution");
            if (success) {  
                System.out.println("Command Executed Successfully.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Command Failed!");
            }
            // Get the command results
            System.out.println("Getting output");
            AS400Message[] messageList;
            messageList  = cmd.getMessageList();
            for (AS400Message message : messageList){
               System.out.println(message.getText());
            }


        }                       
    }catch(UnknownHostException uh){
        System.out.println("Unknown host");         
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        scanner.close();
        try {

            as400.disconnectAllServices();

        }catch(Exception e) {}
    }
```

When I try to run DSPLIBL however: I get a blank output.

```
Ready for input, type "quit" to end session
dsplibl
Command entered: dsplibl
Executing: dsplibl
Finished execution
Command Executed Successfully.
Getting output
Ready for input, type "quit" to end session
```

Everything else seems okay however. CRTLIB *library name* works just fine, and it returns an output message.  Invalid commands also returns messages saying that the input is invalid.  It's just DSPLIBL not giving me an output.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/cmdc.htm) says specifically that CommandCall

> allows a Java™ program to call a non-interactive IBM® i command.

DSPLIBL is an interactive command.

The "output" you're successfully returning for CRTLIB is a completion message returned by that command.

Check out the [getUserLibraryList() method of the Job object](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/Job.html#getUserLibraryList())

Comment: Based on the docs for DSPLIBL "The output is displayed (if requested by an interactive job) or printed with the job's spooled output (if requested by a batch job).", I wonder if a spooled output file ended up in some out queue (similar to what you would get with the *PRINT parameter) when the original program called DSPLIBL this way.

Comment: @Mike I believe you are correct...it would have created a spool file with the library list.